# Как выполнить проверку вводимых данных в textarea

Tags: jquery

Хочу проверять так:
если 32 символа без пробела, то выводим сообщение "вводите норм слова"

Answer (score 1):

На клиенте желательно делать простую проверку, что бы отсекать явно неверные варианты. Ограничение на длину - это вполне нормальное дело. Другое дело, что input умеет и сам это. (`<input type="text" maxlength="число">`). Легкий гуглинг привел сразу на страницу [с примерами](http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/ysC7L/).

А вот проверка на сервере - обязательна. Некоторые пользователи могут направить запрос ручками (например, curl'ом) и сломать сервер. И не нужно бояться за сервер - он железный:) (но я не призываю писать кривой код, который будет перегружать сервер понапрасну).

Answer (score 0):

Зачем делать это во фронт-енде? По мне так бесполезный кусок. Все равно проверку на сервере надо, а этого и достаточно.

Comment: Я пересылаю проверенные данный ajax'ом на сервер он добавляет в базу и перенаправляет на созданную страницу... а если проверять все на сервере:

1. не нагружает ли его это лишний раз
2. и опять же пересылать данные о ошибках, обрабатывать их, и смотреть что дальше делать с ними..
как по мне это лишнее